# Checking which socket answered first C++

Tags: c++, sockets, select

I'm sending a message to two clients and waiting for both of them to respond.
I've got to retrieve the SOCKET value of the socket that answered first but  select only returns 1,0 or -1. How do I edit my code so I can get that value?

```
fd_set readSet;
    FD_ZERO(&readSet);
    FD_SET(actionGuy, &readSet);
    FD_SET(actionAnotherGuy, &readSet);
    send(actionGuy, "go", 3, 0);
    send(actionAnotherGuy, "go", 3, 0);
    SOCKET first = select(actionGuy + 1, &readSet, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select()` returns -1 on error, 0 on timeout, and >0 if 1+ sockets have satisfied the wait.  The `fd_set` is modified accordingly (so you have to reset the `fd_set` every time you call `select()`).  You have to analyze the modified `fd_set` to know which socket(s) are ready.

Also, on non-Windows platforms, the first parameter of `select()` needs to be the highest socket value in the `fd_set(s)` +1, but you are using `actionGuy + 1` instead, which will not work if `actionAnotherGuy` has a higher value than `actionGuy` (on Windows, the first parameter is ignored).

Try something more like this instead:

```
fd_set readSet;
FD_ZERO(&readSet);
FD_SET(actionGuy, &readSet);
FD_SET(actionAnotherGuy, &readSet);

send(actionGuy, "go", 3, 0);
send(actionAnotherGuy, "go", 3, 0);

#ifdef MSWINDOWS
int ret = select(0, &readSet, NULL, NULL, NULL);
#else
int max_fd = max(actionGuy, actionAnotherGuy);
int ret = select(max_fd + 1, &readSet, NULL, NULL, NULL);
#endif

if (ret < 0) {
    // error
}
else if (ret == 0) {
    // timeout
}
else
{
    // at least one socket is readable

    if (FD_ISSET(actionGuy, &readSet)) {
        // actionGuy is readable
    }

    if (FD_ISSET(actionAnotherGuy, &readSet)) {
        // actionAnotherGuy is readable
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If they both became readable in the same invocation of `select()`, they both became readable at essentially the same time. The kernel was unable to separate them: you can't. If there was a significant interval, they would have become readable in separate `select()` invocations.

Comment: The kernel will separate them since the timespan depends on an actual user.

Comment: @НикитаПогуца As I have already stated, If they are separable, the kernel will separate them. If there is a significant interval, the one that fired first will cause `select()` to return immediately. In which case you don't have a problem.